# Matlab finite difference method

Tags: matlab

I've got a little problem with code in matlab. I have found the code:

```
% Finite difference example: cubic function
% f(x)=x^3+x^2-1.25x-0.75
% finite difference approximation to 1st derivative, error O(h)
x=-2:0.1:1.2;
plot(x, polyval([3 2 -1.25],x), 'g-');  % analytical 1st derivative
h=0.4;    % step size
n=(1.2-(-2))/h+1;
x=-2:h:1.2
f=polyval([1, 1, -1.25, -0.75], x)
f1=conv([1, -1], f)  % finite differences, only f1(2:9) are useful
f1=f1(2:9)/h % approximation to 1st derivative
hold on; % keep the above graph
plot(x(1:8)+h/2, f1,'r-');  % FD approximation to 1st derivative
hold off;
```

And I need to edit the code, that instead of fixed "x^3+x^2-1.25x-0.75" I could define the parameters myself in the main window of matlab. In other words I want to change it into the function.

Comment: What is your question? How to change this into a function?

Comment: My question is, how to change this code, that I can define parameters by x every time, instead of putting it in code "x^3+x^2-1.25x-0.75".

Comment: You want to parametrize it in terms of `x`?  Or`h`, `n`, coefficients of the polynomial?  Do you have an example of the output/behavior or something you've tried that's failed?  Sorry if I'm being difficult, but I just want to determine the scope of the question since parametrizing a function like this can be simple or extremely complicated depending on the intended application.

Comment: I mean a very simple thing, I believe. The thing is that here, in the code I copied, the function is  "x^3+x^2-1.25x-0.75". It is a function in which parameters A,B,C,D are: 1, 1, -1.25, -0.75. I just want to have a possibility to determinig these parameters myself when I'm using this function, so I can have another function (for example 3x^2+7x^2-3x+4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use this function for an arbitrary polynomial, you need to define a vector `p` that contains the `n+1` coefficients of the `n` degree polynomial.  In this case:

```
p = [1, 1, -1.25, -0.75];
f = polyval(p, x);
```

And the calculation of the analytical derivative can be attained using [`polyder`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyder.html), which returns the coefficients for the derivative:

```
dfdx = polyval(polyder(p),x);
```